# Factor out imaginary unit of root of obviously negative term

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Suppose I have the term $t=\sqrt{-a^2-b^2}$, where $a,b\in\mathbb R$. Of course, we know that it holds
$$
t = \mathbb i \sqrt{a^2+b^2}
$$
which is (in my opinion) more convenient. How can I get *Mathematica* to factor this out? Especially for things like
$$
\cosh(\sqrt{-a^2-b^2}) = \cos(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})
$$
it would be very helpful, but `FullSimplify` does not do it:

```
In[29]:= FullSimplify[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2], {a ∈ Reals, b ∈ Reals}]
Out[29]= Sqrt[-a^2-b^2]
In[30]:= FullSimplify[Cosh[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2]], {a ∈ Reals, b ∈ Reals}]
Out[30]= Cosh[Sqrt[-a^2-b^2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

In these cases, you need to specify the variables are $>0$. Of course it also works for $<0$, but it just works this way in the software.

```
FullSimplify[Cosh[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2]], {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

> Cos[Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]]

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2], {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

> I Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]

Comment: I just saw that `FullSimplify[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2], {a^2 > 0, b^2 > 0}]` works, as well but `FullSimplify[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2], {a^2 >= 0, b^2 >= 0}]` does not. Any explanation for this weird behaviour?

Comment: @Wauzl It also works for `{a^2 >= 0, b^2 > 0}`, I guess the software needs to know at least one of them isn't `0`. Otherwise the solution set contains two possibilities, `I Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]` and `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Using an undocumented function:

```
Cosh[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2]] /. Sqrt[expr_] /; Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[expr] :> I Sqrt[-expr]
   Cos[Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]]
```

Comment: How save/portable is it to use such a function?

Comment: As with everything that's undocumented: *caveat emptor*.